# New SBS2011 box not setting up Internet

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-sbs

A customer has asked for help with this, and given me remote access, and my Google searching is not helping. SU doesn't seem to have anyone available to help in chat currently, so I'm trying here.

I start it up, run the `Setup your Internet address` and `Configure a Smart Host for Internet e-mail` wizards, only to be told that the `Connect to the Internet` wizard must be completed first. Fine, I'll do that.

I start that wizard, it detects the router IP and the Server IP. DHCP and DNS are disabled in the router, and set for the server. At the end of the wizard, I get `Windows SBS did not properly configure your e-mail. To correct this, re-run this wizard`.

Doing googling, I ran PS scripts, re-configured IIS, and none of this has worked. Has the customer screwed over his server? Or is there a way to recover from this point? It is accessing the Internet just fine (proof: I'm remoting to it)

[image]

**EDIT:** Logs uploaded

```
Session "WBCommandletInBuiltTracing" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035

(Process w3wp.exe, PID 6452) "RBAC authorization is unavailable due to the transient error: The Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology service on server localhost did not return any suitable domain controllers."

The mount operation for the gatherer application cf7f8355-fe55-4b3b-a945-060635a824a7 has failed because the schema version of the search administration database is less than the minimum backwards compatibility schema version supported for this gatherer application. The database might not have been upgraded.

The Microsoft Exchange Throttling Service encountered an Active Directory error while building an RPC security descriptor. This failure may indicate that no Domain Controllers are available at this time. The service will be stopped. Failure details: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.NoSuitableServerFoundException: The Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology service on server localhost did not return any suitable domain controllers.
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.DSAccessTopologyProvider.GetConfigDCInfo(Boolean throwOnFailure)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.TopologyProvider.PopulateConfigNamingContexts()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.GetConfigurationNamingContext()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Recipient.ADRecipientSession.GetWellKnownExchangeGroupSid(Guid wkguid)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Recipient.ADRecipientSession.GetExchangeServersUsgSid()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ThrottlingService.ThrottlingRpcServerImpl.GetRpcSecurityDescriptor()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ThrottlingService.ThrottlingRpcServerImpl.c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADNotificationAdapter.RunADOperation(ADOperation adOperation, Int32 retryCount)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADNotificationAdapter.TryRunADOperation(ADOperation adOperation, Int32 retryCount)

An unexpected error occurred while starting the Microsoft Exchange Address Book service. Error details: The wait operation timed out (258)

The Mailbox Replication service was unable to determine the list of mailbox databases hosted in the local Active Directory site.
Error: The Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology service on server localhost did not return any suitable domain controllers.
```

**EDIT 2**: As per request, here is the DNS Forwarders configuration inside of the DNS MMC snapin:
[image]

Comment: Why are you even running the wizards if the box already has internet access?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg It's the customer's box, that he can't get working :-/ The Exchange connector isn't working, so I know it's not an email issue. They do want the Exchange Server running on it htough

Comment: Have you suggested that maybe he should try running his Exchange server on a real OS?  Or going with a hosted Exchange solution?  Well, that probably not particularly helpful, but maybe the event log entries saying *why* the wizard failed would be of use.  SBS does have event logs... doesn't it?

Comment: @HopelessN00b Yes it does. What logs would you like?

Comment: Oh dear, God... what fresh hell is this?  I would suggest posting the app and system event logs showing errors that correspond to the wizard(s) not being applied correctly... but honestly, it might be more productive to assign a domain and create an SMTP smarthost manually.  Though a though does occur:  Windows often prevents you from changing network settings when you're TSed in, to protect you from yourself.  Try connecting with `mstsc /console` and see if that gets you better results on those network wizards.

Comment: @HopelessN00b OK, I will try connecting with console mode, try my troubleshooting again, and post back

Comment: @HopelessN00b you are not supposed to do "manual" configuration with an SBS - it's all wizardry land there.

Comment: The customer decided that a wipe and reload was a lot easier. Feel free to close as Too Localized, as I won't be able to select an answer otherwise

Comment: @HopelessN00b Exchange is made to run on SBS. What's not real about that?

Comment: @WesleyDavid  You mean, MS made their not-a-real-OS product compatible with the mail server?  Shocking.  What makes SBS not a real OS is everything else about it, primarily its effort to make a server OS that's aimed at and marketed at people who're not technically knowledgeable enough to actually run a server.

Comment: @HopelessN00b How is it not a real OS? It does OS functions, therefore it's an OS

Answer (score 0):

> DHCP and DNS are disabled in the router, and set for the server

You likely have an issue with DNS resolution. The SBS has been designed with the idea of a working company router in mind. While disabling the DHCP server on the router is a good idea, disabling the DNS forwarder is not, as the SBS will try to resolve any of its own external requests through the router's forwarder.

Simply re-enabling the DNS forwarder on the router and re-running the "connect to the internet" wizard should help here.

Comment: The DNS forwarder was set to 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS). I added the Router as another forwarder, and turned DNS back on in the router. Running the wizard - No change, even after restarting the DNS Server service

Comment: @Luke have you double-checked that it is the *forwarder* which is set (i.e. a forwarder setting in the DNS Server MMC snapin) and not the *resolver* in the TCP/IP configuration of the server? The latter has *always* to point to the SBS server itself, otherwise domain location and any depending services would not work.

Comment: See edit with picture

Answer (score 0):

I've recently put an SBS2011 and had lots of problems .. it was really fussy!...

Try running "Fix my network" even though it is connected to the internet anyway and just use the same information and make sure you haven't got any other domain controllers or DHCP servers on the same network.

This sorted my problem, as I manually configured my NICs .. it really doesn't like people changing anything manually